# Grepping for Python processes

Tags: python, process, pid

I'm running a script that executes either:

```
./ide.py
# or
python ./ide.py
```

After that I use `pstree -p | grep ide.py` to check, but I only found a Python process.  If I have many Python scripts running, how can I distinguish them from each other?

Comment: question seems to be more suitable for http://superuser.com

Comment: although pstree is a good command i prefer ps fax which is more informative about commands

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-a` switch:

```
pstree -p -a
```

to show process command line arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the pstree command with the "-a" switch to show command line arguments.  Here's why:

All python scripts are run through the python interpreter...  Even if you run them directly (i.e. ./ide.py).